# How to insert only numbers and letter should display a message or something

Tags: c++, input, console, numbers, int

If I enter a letter like "x" I get a message loop "Incorrect option" and it never stops.

```
int option=0;

    while(option != 2)
    {
        cout << "Select option: ";
        cin >> option;

        switch (option){
            case 1: 
                cout << "\n Selected option: " << option << endl<<endl;
                system("pause"); 
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2: 
                cout << "\n BYE BYE: " << option << endl << endl;
                system("pause"); 
                option = 2;
                break;
            default: 
                cout << "\n > Incorrect option" << endl<<endl;
                option=0;
                system("pause"); 
                system("cls");
        }

    }
```

I want when I insert a letter when I ask an int number show a message and do something.

Comment: In case of default, should clear the error flag by cin.clear();

Answer (score 2):

You get that infinitely because `x` is not a valid `int`, so the `cin >> option` fails.  You need to clear the input buffer and reset the fail bit if the input fails:

```
while (!(cin >> option))
{
    cout << "Enter a valid option!" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

...
```

This will allow you to select a new option.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'int option' to be be 'char option'.

Change 'case 1:' to be 'case '1':'

'1' will return the ASCII value for the character '1' which isn't 1, it's 49. (Do the same for three and two)

Comment: but if I enter "xx" shows me 2 times the message "Incorrect option" because he thinks that I introduce two char